# How to use Linear regression when my **X** values are normally distributed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

To be more specific the error variance of the `x` value is half of the variance of error in `y`.

I looked over sklearn and couldn't find a function which takes the error variance of `x` into account.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand the question. But if I understand it correctly, you are trying to use linear regression to find the linear model with maximum likelihood. In other words, an error for data where X and Y are uncertain is less serious that one where X and Y are very accurate.

If that is so, what people do in such case, is usually to weight each sample with inverse of error variance.

With `sklearn`, weight is simply the 3rd (optionnal) parameter of `.fit`

So I would

```py
lin=LinearRegression()
lin.fit(X, Y, 1/variance(X))
```

`variance(X)` being your evaluation of X variance.

### Edit (after your comment)

Then I don't get the question. The fact that X and Y measure have an error, that those error do not have the same magnitude (anyway, "same magnitude" about a weight and a size would be meaningless), etc. is not a problem. If there were no error, then you wouldn't be doing a linear regression, would you? As long as those error have a 0 expected value (and if not, just remove the expected value of the error from the variable :D), and are not correlated... (so, being independent is a sufficient condition)

That is Gauss-Markov hypothesis, and it is the foundation of the least square method (the one used by sklearn).

If you know something else from your error, then, back to my first answer. But if all you know is that the error on Y tends to be bigger than error on X, then, there is no problem to solve.

Comment: First of all thank you for your willingness to help,
I had tried implementing what you wrote but unfortunately this doesn't work, I should have been more clear and note that I am referring to a local error in the measure of X( for example, the weight scale is a bit broken so that the measuring of the x values isn't very accurate, but the measuring of the height(y value) is even less accurate )
If you have any idea what I could do in such a case it would be great to know

Comment: @NadavBanay See my edit (tho, I may again have misundertood something. But if I haven't, then you have no problem to solve. Having errors on data is not only not a problem for linear regression, but is also usually the reason why we need a linear regression in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who might find it useful,
the lecturer told us the answer, it required using DEMING REGRESSION